# Google Cloud SQL Postgres Time Zones

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

Having a hard time correcting a whole bunch of datetime errors after migrating a local postgres database from a local machine to Google Cloud SQL postgres instance.

The original database has a significant amount of data in it, using timestamp fields where the dates where supplied from Windows and PHP applications using local timestamps (CST/CDT ... 'America/Winnipeg').  The original server was configured for 'America/Winnipeg' time zone.  On top of this I have a significant number of views/functions/procedures (hundreds of each) that use timestamp math in order to determine durations between timestamps in minutes (aka: payroll/attendance).  All of these are now fubar as current_timestamp, localtimestamp and now() all return UTC values.

Attempting to SET TIMEZONE goes nowhere.  The command runs but nothing changes.

I have large number of apps giving strange results (VB.Net, C#, PHP, Winforms, Blazor, etc.)

Does anybody have any idea how to address this?

Comment: This question lacks detail. For example, are your columns of type `timestamp with time zone` or of type `timestamp` (without time zone)? `SET timezone` will work, but you have to do it in each database session. To get the current time in your time zone, you can use `current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Winnipeg'`.

Comment: All columns are timestamp without time zone. Looks like I have a lot of work to do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have four options:

1. Change the `timezone` parameter in the `postgresql.conf` file on the server or with `ALTER SYSTEM`. Upon reload, that will take effect in all sessions that do not override the parameter.
2. Change the `timezone` parameter with

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE ... SET timezone = 'America/Winnipeg';
   ```

   That will work for every new database session that does not override the parameter.
3. Change the parameter in each database session with

   ```
   SET timezone = 'America/Winnipeg';
   ```
4. Instead of `current_timestamp`, use

   ```
   current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Winnipeg'
   ```

   everywhere.

Comment: Option 1 does not appear to be an option as this is Google SQL postgres and I do not believe we have access to postgresql.conf.  I could easily be wrong.  I attempted the ALTER DATABASE ... command from pgadmin, it had no effect.  In theory my .Net apps using Npgsql should be able to set the PGTZ environment variable in the connection string.  But all testing to far blows chunks trying to set this parameter: PGTZ=CDT or PGTZ=CST or PGTZ=America/Winnipeg ... Postgres docs seems to indicate CST and CDT which means my app will have to monitor dates to see when standard/savings times change.

Comment: I am sure that Google provides a way to change parameters. But maybe your problem is really something different, perhaps related to .NET or Npgsql. Otherwise, my answer should have helped. To debug, look how the timestamps actually show up on the PostgreSQL end (logging can help).